# Create exception for like already assigned in the InstaPy library

Tags: python, instagram, except, instapy

I have the algorithm below that performs likes and comments on instagram photos via URL, my goal is to run this script on an AWS machine within 5 minutes which will generate 288 comments per day. However, whenever he realizes that he already executes LIKE in the photo, he returns `"LIKED 0 images  |  ALREADY LIKED: 1"`, and aborts the process. I wanted to create a deal for when LIKE already exists, just execute the comment, is it possible? If yes you can help me with provisioning examples or the solution in question, thank you!

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

def connect(insta_username,insta_password):

    try:

        session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                        password=insta_password,
                        headless_browser=False)

        return session

    except Exception as e:
        print("[FAILED] Caused by: {}".format(e))

def action(url,insta_username,insta_password):

    session = connect(insta_username,insta_password)

    try:

        with smart_run(session):

            # Always follow and like before, the algorithm understands how it has already been executed when used in place of the like function
            # Define interaction settings
            session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=100)
            session.set_comments(["@user-id"])
            session.set_user_interact(amount=1, randomize=False, percentage=100, media='Photo')

            # Start the feature
            session.interact_by_URL(urls=url, randomize=False, interact=True)
            session.end()

    except Exception as e:
        print("[FAILED] Caused by: {}".format(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pics = ["https://www.instagram.com/p/id-here"]
    for url in pics:
        action(url,'username','password')
```